# Is there any restriction on custom URI scheme registration in IOS app

Tags: ios, url, url-scheme

Is there any restriction on custom URI scheme registration(maximum no of URI scheme for an app) ?  I have gone through the Apple documentations, but I could not find any info on this .

My requirement is to register multiple URI scheme within the same app like below URI.

SampleV1://
SampleV2://
SampleV3://
……
……
……
SampleVn://

Please let me know if anyone has already done the same.